# datatables.net add a class to the search label

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

```
<label>Search: <input type="text" aria-controls="company"></label>
```

Using [Datatables](http://datatables.net), how would i added a class to the search field input box?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Depending which example are you using.. if you are using the following  http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/zero_config.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();
    $('#example_filter input').addClass('yourclass'); // <-- add this line
} );
```

P.S.: If the table have more input search or you have more tables, you can refer to all the input search by using the `class selector` `(".someClass")`

Comment: If you use the class instead of the id (which is relative to the id of the table) you have a more consistent result, imho.

Answer (score 8):

I'd do

```
$('.dataTables_filter input').addClass('yourclass');
```

of course add this after you initialize your table

Comment: I'd agree - why the need for a class on the input when you can use a selector based on the class from the parent element?

Comment: @AllanJardine Because some UI frameworks (ie. Bootstrap) call for classes applied to things like input fields.

Answer (score 7):

i'm use DataTable 1.10.x and Bootstrap :

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
    "sFilterInput": "form-control yourClass",
    "sLengthSelect": "form-control yourClass"
});
```

I go through the extend function instead of jquery. :)

Comment: This sets it globally, though, right? So, if I have more than a single data-table, and for some reason, I wanted them not to be the same, then this wouldn't work out for me.